# Dynamic creation of barplot in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart

So, say I have three datasets `D1,D2,D3` I can use [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py) guide to create the bars next to each other. Say I don't know how many data sets I have, lets call the number `N`, is there a way to create `N` bars aligned around the x-ticks, without the placement-parameters in `ax.bars` (`x - width/2`)? Or do I have to create the placement dynamically?

Comment: It is much easier to use [pandas bar plots](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) to get what you need.

Comment: I have used around 2 hours to make the plots working - your solution took around 2 minutes! Feel free to post it as answer